# blur bootstrap card's image on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to blur an image of a bootstrap card on a hover, but it's not working. Blur is working fine without the hover.

Here is my code (but I tried many things) :

```css
.card-img {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(0px);
}

.card-img:hover {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card bg-dark text-white mt-4 mb-3 border-dark">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://www.flightnetwork.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/header-journey11.jpg" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h1 class="card-title underline">Bienvenue sur le site de Motard d'Alsace !</h1>
      <p class="card-text p1 bg-dark">Trouve dès maintenant ta prochaine balade moto</p>
      <p class="card-text bg-dark">Ou partage tes propositions de balades !</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The image is blurred when I hover over it in both firefox and chrome. What is the problem?

Comment: @abney317 uuuuh, literaly not working for me, https://motard-alsace.mygsxr.fr/
Problem is somewhere else then, thanks

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't including bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `card-img-overlay` covers the entire `card-img` element. So it can't tell that you're hovering over the `card-img` div.

To fix this, check for a hover of the parent card, and exclude the `card-img-overlay` from the selector.

```css
.card-img {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(0px);
}

.card:hover > *:not(.card-img-overlay) {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card bg-dark text-white mt-4 mb-3 border-dark">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://www.flightnetwork.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/header-journey11.jpg" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h1 class="card-title underline">Bienvenue sur le site de Motard d'Alsace !</h1>
      <p class="card-text p1 bg-dark">Trouve dès maintenant ta prochaine balade moto</p>
      <p class="card-text bg-dark">Ou partage tes propositions de balades !</p>
    </div>
</div>
```